# Using VBA to open a PDF file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm using the following code to open a specific file (of any type) from Excel:

```
Function OpenFile(ByRef fileFullName As String)

OpenTheFile:
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (fileFullName)
    
    Dim fileOpenCheck As Boolean
    fileOpenCheck = IsFileOpen(fileFullName)
    
    If fileOpenCheck = True Then
        ' DO NOTHING - File is open
    Else
        GoTo OpenTheFile
    End If
    
End Function

Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)
    
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNum As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNum = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNum
        Case 0
            IsFileOpen = False
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True
        Case Else
            Error ErrNo
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Can anybody explain why PDFs never open the FIRST time I run this code, despite the code executing to completion? Also, how can I alter the code so as to avoid this issue and have this file type open on the first execution?

Answer (score 0):

The code `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (fileFullName)` is opening PDF application (like Adobe Reader) first and then default application second (like Edge) when already opened in the PDF application.
You can open a file with `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (fileFullName)` to open it in the default application at first.

On a side note, I moved the code to open the file in the if statement because it was causing infinite loop using your GoTo.

```vb
    Function OpenFile(Optional ByRef fileFullName As String)
        
        Dim fileOpenCheck As Boolean
        fileOpenCheck = IsFileOpen(fileFullName)
        
        If fileOpenCheck = True Then
            ' DO NOTHING - File is open
        Else
            CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (fileFullName)
        End If
        
    End Function
    
    Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)
        
        Dim ff As Long, ErrNum As Long
    
        On Error Resume Next
        ff = FreeFile()
        Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
        Close ff
        ErrNum = Err
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        Select Case ErrNum
            Case 0
                IsFileOpen = False
            Case 70
                IsFileOpen = True
            Case Else
                Error ErrNo
        End Select
        
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (fileFullName)` as this does - eventually - open the file, whereas `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (fileFullName)` did not, despite `IsFileOpen` returning a value of TRUE. I stuck with the loop (which doesn't create an infinite loop!) as a debug statement indicated that the file failed to open several times before finally opening (which was the intended purpose of the loop).